# Duck curry with pineapple pieces

Tags: curry, duck

Should I use panang paste or red paste when making a duck curry. I have tried red.

Comment: So how did the recipe with the red curry paste turn out?

Answer (score 1):

Panang paste usually contains peanuts and tastes sweeter, so it depends on how you feel they go with duck.